How to install ceiling fan box when distance from joist to ceiling is not standard?
I have another question related to installing a ceiling fan box. My plan was to install a ceiling fan box in a location that had a standard box already installed on a plywood spacer glued to a joist.  (I do not have access to this area from above.) The 3/4" plywood spacer leaves 1 3/4" space from the bottom of the plywood to the ceiling, such that a standard 1 1/2" box is recessed into the ceiling by 1/4".

I have a few questions on this situation:

The box I planned to use has a lip which I assume should be flush to the ceiling.  However, I am wondering if it would be OK to instead install the 1 1/2" box such that it is recessed in the ceiling by 1/4", or a 2" box such that it would protrude from the ceiling by 1/4".  Do either of these scenarios work, or is a 1/4" gap too much?
Can I add a 1/4" spacer to the piece of plywood in there already so that I can use a 1 1/2" box or will this add some weakness?  If you think it OK to add another spacer what would you suggest?  Gluing a 1/4 piece of plywood (any type OK?)?  Something else?
Or should I rip out the old 3/4" spacer and add a 1"spacer?  If so, can you suggest a way to remove the old spacer that is firmly glued on without opening the 4" hole significantly further.



Thanks.  I am an overthinker unfortunately.  One question, when you say 'spacer mount' do you mean a particular piece of hardware (like https://tinyurl.com/4ydhs4m6) or just a plywood spacer?  If you mean a particular piece of hardware, would it be better to use metal or plastic?  Thanks again.

Actually, I was looking into spacer washers and I dont think that would work as the screw holes are too close together.  I think I will take your advice and not overthink it and just glue some thin plywood up there...

Sorry there was supposed to be a comma in there.  just use any piece of wood or plastic that is 1/4 or very close to 1/4 inch...again DON'T overthink this. It's just a spacer and it is not going on a rocket.
